# How to get meta-information (TeXLive-Version, Compiler, -version) inserted in the file?

Tags: luatex, texlive, metadata

Similar to [Colophon in LuaTex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/310961/98739) I would like to get the information of the `TeX Live`-version, the compiler I used (`LuaLaTeX`) and its version into a colophon. 
Additionally the fonts used in the file and e.g. the version of `biblatex`.

This is not for debugging issues but for showing the information in the pdf.

Comment: Please provide an example which includes the elements you want to include.

Comment: Finding package versions is already answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13304/which-package-version-am-i-using) (see Joseph's answer).

Comment: See also: [Which package version am I using? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13304/which-package-version-am-i-using?noredirect=1&lq=1)  and linked questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The LuaTeX version is available through the internal variables `\luatexversion` and `\luatexrevision`.  These are also accessible on the Lua level.  Both major and minor version are encoded in `\luatexversion`, the major version being the result of `\luatexversion/100` and the minor version `mod(\luatexversion,100)`.

The TeXlive version is in the LuaTeX banner, so you can just extract it with regex.

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016)
```

Because it is the only thing in parentheses we match everything inside.  For the Biber version we need to call `biber -v` and read it's output.  Here we match everything after `:`.  However, we need shell escape for that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}
\begin{luacode*}
  tex.sprint("Lua\\TeX{} version "
             .. math.floor(tex.luatexversion / 100) .. "."
             .. math.floor(tex.luatexversion % 100) .. "."
             .. math.floor(tex.luatexrevision))

  local tlversion = string.match(tex.luatexbanner, "%((.*)%)")
  tex.sprint(tlversion)

  local fh = io.popen("biber -v")
  local biberversion = string.match(fh:read(), ":(.*)$")
  tex.sprint(biberversion)
\end{luacode*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And how to get `This is LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0` ?

Comment: @LukasCB See updated answer.